# Amazon MWS: Accessing Array of Matching Products

Tags: php, arrays, amazon-mws

I am Working with MWS for the first time and hoping to create a program that uses the ListMatchingProducts request to average out the prices of every product that matches a query.

It should be a very simple program, but I am having trouble retrieving data.

First I make the call and get amazon's xml sheet, Then I convert the xml to an array.

Print_R shows that the array looks something like this:

```
Array ( [ListMatchingProductsResult] => Array ( [Products] => Array ( [Product] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [Identifiers] => Array ( [MarketplaceASIN] => Array ( [MarketplaceId] => ATVPDKIKX0DER [ASIN] => 0786866020 ) ) [AttributeSets] => Array ( [ItemAttributes] => Array ( [Author] => Array ( [0] => Stephen C. Lundin [1] => Harry Paul [2] => John Christensen ) [Binding] => Hardcover [Brand] => Hyperion [Color] => White [Creator] => Ken Blanchard [Edition] => 1 [Feature] => Great product! [ItemDimensions] => Array ( [Height] => 8.25 [Length] => 5.50 [Width] => 0.00 [Weight] => 0.54 ) [IsAdultProduct] => false [Label] => Hyperion [Languages] => Array ( [Language] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [Name] => english [Type] => Published ) [1] => Array ( [Name] => english [Type] => Original Language ) [2] => Array ( [Name] => english [Type] => Unknown ) ) ) [ListPrice] => Array ( **[Amount] => 21.00** [CurrencyCode] => USD ) [Manufacturer] => Hyperion [ManufacturerMaximumAge] => 1188.0 [ManufacturerMinimumAge] => 156.0 [NumberOfItems] => 1 [NumberOfPages] => 110 [PackageDimensions] => Array ( [Height] => 0.65 [Length] => 8.60 [Width] => 5.65 [Weight] => 0.58 ) [PackageQuantity] => 1 [PartNumber] => 9780786866021 [ProductGroup] => Book [ProductTypeName] => ABIS_BOOK [PublicationDate] => 2000-03-08 [Publisher] => Hyperion [ReleaseDate] => 2000-03-08 [SmallImage] => Array ( [URL] => http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51cHo55tbOL._SL75_.jpg [Height] => 75 [Width] => 47 ) [Studio] => Hyperion [Title] => Fish: A Proven Way to Boost Morale and Improve Results ) ) [Relationships] => Array ( ) [SalesRankings] => Array ( [SalesRank] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [ProductCategoryId] => book_display_on_website [Rank] => 4629 ) [1] => Array ( [ProductCategoryId] => 1043856 [Rank] => 2 ) [2] => Array ( [ProductCategoryId] => 2635 [Rank] => 7 ) [3] => Array ( [ProductCategoryId] => 2637 [Rank] => 18 ) ) ) ) [1] ...
```

I am trying to access the amount part of the array, as this is the price of the object. Eventually, I will need to access the amount of each product and so a loop will likely come into play, but right now i cannot even access one products sales amount.

Here is the code I have been trying

```
$value = $array->ListMatchingProductsResult->Products->Product[0]->ListPrice->Amount;
print_r($value);
```

And it is not working. Even calling print_r on $array->ListMatchingProductsResult is not printing an array.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: Can you also post the error that you get while trying to access the value or while trying to print the object?

Comment: Sorry for the late response zapping! The error was just a blank screen strangely enough!

Comment: I have edited my answer for the 'php blank screen error'.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there. Whatever method you are using to convert the XML to a PHP array however, does just that: It creates an associative *array* of things, not an *object*. That is why you cannot access it through the `->element` operator, but need to use array indexes `['element']`

```
$value = $array['ListMatchingProductsResult']['Products']['Product'][0]['ListPrice']['Amount'];
```

If you're ever wondering why you're not getting something back, you can successily shorten above expresion until you do. So if a `print_r(...)` on above expression returns nothing, just remove one square bracket at a time from that print_r until you do get something back. You then know that the last bracket you removed was the culprit.

```
Array ( 
[ListMatchingProductsResult] => Array ( 
    [Products] => Array ( 
        [Product] => Array ( 
            [0] => Array ( 
                 [Identifiers] => Array ( 
                     [MarketplaceASIN] => Array ( 
                          [MarketplaceId] => ATVPDKIKX0DER 
                          [ASIN] => 0786866020 
                      ) 
                  ) 
                 [AttributeSets] => Array ( 
                     [ItemAttributes] => Array ( 
                          [Author] => Array ( 
                               [0] => Stephen C. Lundin 
                               [1] => Harry Paul
                               [2] => John Christensen 
                          ) 
                          [Binding] => Hardcover 
                          [Brand] => Hyperion 
                          [Color] => White 
                          [Creator] => Ken Blanchard
                          [Edition] => 1
                          [Feature] => Great product!
                          [ItemDimensions] => Array ( 
                              [Height] => 8.25 
                              [Length] => 5.50 
                              [Width] => 0.00 
                              [Weight] => 0.54 
                          )
                          [IsAdultProduct] => false 
                          [Label] => Hyperion 
                          [Languages] => Array ( 
                              [Language] => Array ( 
                                  [0] => Array ( 
                                       [Name] => english 
                                       [Type] => Published 
                                  ) 
                                  [1] => Array ( 
                                       [Name] => english 
                                       [Type] => Original Language 
                                  ) 
                                  [2] => Array ( 
                                       [Name] => english 
                                       [Type] => Unknown 
                                  ) 
                              ) 
                          ) 
                          [ListPrice] => Array (
                              [Amount] => 21.00 
                              [CurrencyCode] => USD 
                          ) 
                          [Manufacturer] => Hyperion 
                 ...
```

BTW, using `<pre>...</pre>` is helpful when trying to make sense of `print_r()` or `var_dump()`.

P.S. You owe me a new space key.

Comment: Thanks a ton hahah! That was a very blatant error in retrospect.
I am trying it now and will report back with the fixed code. Unfortunately I made an account just to ask this question and so don't have the reputation to upvote your answer but i do appreciate it!

Comment: Lol just talked to a friend about the space key coment. Didn't realize i needed to hit it for each line. I now have a whole new appreciation for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an sdk library that uses the ListMatchingProducts of Amazon MWS. You will be able to get the info in accessing info required.

https://github.com/choomz/amazon-mws-sdk/blob/master/search/src/MarketplaceWebServiceProducts/Samples/ListMatchingProductsSample.php

---

To show php errors have this set in your php.in

```
display_errors = On
```

You can also give this on top of the php script

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

Comment: Im sorry can you elaborate on this one? As you may have been able to tell i am new to php, i am using this as a first project to teach myself for a class. What is that code? I also have that in the sdk I believe, but i did not realize it would let me grab prices from the xml response! It seems as if that is getting an object of some sort directly from amazon's servers?

Comment: @MatthewSciamanna That looks like a copy of the "official" PHP SDK that Amazon provides. I don't see the point in using that over the Amazon one. Also, using that PHP library instead will *not* solve your initial problem.

Comment: @Hazzit Oh Okay great I couldn't figure the benefits out at first either. Ill stick to the array then thanks!